# Mongoose can't find my data from database but database has been connected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

It has show "Database connected" , I think database has already connected to mongodb server already. However ,there has nothing to be console log.  Data is null here and nothing is print on my page.

Here is my code.

*index.js*

```
var userModel = require('../models/userModel.js');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db', { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log("connect fail");

        console.log("Database connected");

    });

})

userModel.find({}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err)
    }

    console.log(data);

    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Account', user: data, loginStatus: isLogin
    });
})
```

*models/userModel.js*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,

    account: String,

    password: String,

    email: String

 });

 var model = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);


module.exports = model;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this is you're connecting database on api call which should never be the case. You should always do it in the beginning and call the collections at the endpoints. Now whenever you'll call '/' check server console.

```
var userModel = require('../models/userModel.js');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db', { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log("connect fail");
    console.log("Database connected");
});
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
   userModel.find({}, function (err, data) {
     if (err) {
        return console.log(err)
     }
     console.log(data);

     res.render('index', {
        title: 'Account', user: data, loginStatus: isLogin
     });
   })
})
```